# How put % in stored procedure for a variable @?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSoNumber (@SO varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderNo
    FROM Orders_Header
    WHERE (DVMOrderNumber LIKE '%'@SO & '%') 
End
```

How can I apply the SQL `LIKE` wildcard (`%`) on a variable (`@SO`) within a stored procedure?

I tried with `'%@SO%'`, but doesn't work.

I want to select partial text and use it to search the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSoNumber (@SO varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderNo
    FROM Orders_Header
    WHERE (DVMOrderNumber LIKE '%' + @SO + '%') 
End
```

This is just a normal string concatenation.

Comment: That a lot, when i use code in vb.net i put & not plus, but work. Thanksa lot

Comment: Yes, well, T-SQL is not the same as VB.NET ;-) Please mark the answer that helped you as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I presume that is SQL Server T-SQL? If that so, use this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSoNumber (@SO varchar(255)) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderNo
    FROM Orders_Header
    WHERE (DVMOrderNumber LIKE '%' + @SO + '%') 
END
```

In Oracle, concatenation use "||", so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSoNumber (@SO varchar(255)) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderNo
    FROM Orders_Header
    WHERE (DVMOrderNumber LIKE '%' || @SO || '%') 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSoNumber (@SO varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
   declare @varSO varchar(225)='%%'

   if  @SO is not null
     set @varSO='%'+@SO+'%' 

   SELECT OrderNo
   FROM Orders_Header
   WHERE DVMOrderNumber LIKE @varSO

End
```